# What Capabilities are Required to Post?

Tags: support, browser-support

In my browser I use NoScript, a cookie management plug-in, uBlock Origin, HTTPS Everywhere, and a plug-in to set my user agent string. I find it difficult to post sometimes, especially if a Captcha is required, but I don't know what to enable as I do not know what capabilities the site requires. Could someone help me understand what is needed to use the site as intended?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: sstatic is crucial.

Comment: NoScript and the cookie management plugin may be interfering, but uBlock should not, I don't believe that HTTPS Everywhere interferes with posting questions, nor should changing the user agent string interfere.

Comment: I know I also have issues trying to log in if I'm using the GoogleBot user agent. This might be a cookie issue, but the server does appear to handle requests from different user agents differently.

Comment: Specifically the log-in issues I see are a redirect which doesn't complete.

Comment: Why not simply disable each of your customisations one by one and see which one or ones make life difficult for yourself?

Comment: Browsing the internet is definitely too easy.